# Программа, перебирая элементы массива на условия, выдает на каждом этапе удовл. результат вместо одного итогового

Tags: c, массивы

```
int sumlessM(int a[], int n, int M) {
    int sum;

    printf("\nВведите предел чисел массива: \n");
    scanf("%i", &M);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] < M) {
            sum += a[i];
            printf("\nСумма чисел меньше заданного: %i\n", sum);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int maxElemnon(int a[], int n) {
    int maxElem;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] % 2 != 0 && a[i] > maxElem) {
            maxElem = a[i];
            printf("\nМаксимальное нечетное значение в массиве: %i\n", maxElem);
        }
    }
    return maxElem;
}`
```

Пояснение:

При созданном массиве из 10 элементов:

```
40 6 39 45 2 47 3 42 50 13
```

на выходе при заданном пределе значения элементов 46 имею:

> ```
> Сумма чисел меньше заданного: 40
> Сумма чисел меньше заданного: 46
> Сумма чисел меньше заданного: 85
> Сумма чисел меньше заданного: 130
> Сумма чисел меньше заданного: 132
> Сумма чисел меньше заданного: 135
> Сумма чисел меньше заданного: 177
> Сумма чисел меньше заданного: 190
> ```

Ситуация такого же рода и со вторым куском кода тоже.

Comment: printf за цикл, пожалуйста.

Comment: Не очень понятно, зачем в функции `sumlessM` вы передаете `int M` в качестве параметра, при этом сразу изменяя его с помощью `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит потому что вы вызываете вывод в каждой итерации цикла. Исправьте код следующим образом:

```
int sumlessM(int a[], int n, int M) {
    int sum;

    printf("\nВведите предел чисел массива: \n");
    scanf("%i", &M);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += a[i];
    }

    if (sum < M) {
        printf("\nСумма чисел меньше заданного: %i\n", sum);
    }

    return sum;
}

int maxElemnon(int a[], int n) {
    int maxElem;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] % 2 != 0 && a[i] > maxElem) {
            maxElem = a[i];
        }
    }
    printf("\nМаксимальное нечетное значение в массиве: %i\n", maxElem);
    return maxElem;
}
```

**WARNING**

Архитектура отраженная в данном коде является в корне неверной. Тут отображено только как исправить, то о чем задал вопрос автор. В общем и целом использовать представленный кусок кода в чистом виде не рекомендуется.

Comment: А что будет в `int maxElem` и в `int sum` при входе в функцию?
И что будет, если в массиве нет нечетных чисел?

Comment: @ Ternvein, автор задал конкретный вопрос и получил конкретный ответ. Моя задача была не вылизывать чужой код, а дать ответ почему происходит печать после каждого сравнения. Так что ваше замечание по поводу возможных эксепшенов не уместно. В общем в коде автора исправлено исключительно, то что интересовало автора.

Comment: В таком случае не стоит писать *Исправьте код следующим образом*, а указать на конкретные ошибки. Если вы прикладываете код в ответ, стоит убедиться, что он хотя бы не содержит ошибок и UB.

Comment: @Ternvein, если уж на то пошло, то внутри метода не должно быть никаких считываний значений из консолей и вывода.
Либо методы не должны возвращать значение. В данном коде в корне кривая архитектура, но автор явно новичок и не поймет если я начну указывать ему на все ошибки в коде. Потому я решил ему помочь тем в чем конкретно был его вопрос.

Comment: @Ternvein, специально для вас дополнил ответ)